# .NET: Any way to tell when an object is disposed/garbage collected?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

Given an object, is there any way to get notified of when that object is garbage collected?

I am playing around with having C# extension methods behave a little more like mixins (specifically in adding logging).  So basically each object gets a new Logger() method which returns an ILog that is created and cached depending on the object that is the extension method's target.

Works pretty swell, the only concern is obviously after an object goes away its logger might hang around for quite some time.  I could of course set up some periodic mechanism to sweep through the logger cache and clear it but I would much rather set up some a Garbage-Collection notification so I learn about when the system is no longer using my objects.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what's generally done here is that you maintain a list of [WeakReferences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx).  With a weak reference, you can tell if the object you're referring to has been garbage-collected or not by checking the [IsAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.isalive.aspx) property.

Answer (score 3):

In .net 4.0, there is a type `ConditionalWeakTable` which may be used, albeit somewhat awkwardly, to request notification when an arbitrary object becomes eligible for finalization.  If a `ConditionalWeakTable` contains an entry mapping one object (say the 451st object created) to another object (say the 730th object created), then as long as the entry remains in the table, and rooted references exist both to the table and to object #451, the table will be considered a rooted reference to object #730.  If no rooted reference exists to object #451, the table will cease to be a rooted reference to object #730.

Consequently, if object #730 holds a reference to the table and to object #730 exists outside the table, object #730 will become eligible for finalization at the same time as object #451.  If object #730 overrides `Finalize()`, that override can be used as a notification that object #451 has become eligible for finalization.

Note that the finalizer for object #730 will only fire once even if object #451 resurrects itself and re-registers for finalization.  It would be possible to write code which would fire notification around the time when object #451 truly becomes dead and buried, even if it gets resurrected a few times first, but there's no particularly clean way to do so.

Comment: It would be super awesome to have a class that manages this and abstracts the ugly, providing the calling client with a pretty interface, FWIW. Also, from what I am reading, it sounds like an object can only be resurrected once?  Is that accurate? Source: http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2014/08/20/short-vs-long-weak-references-and-object-resurrection/

Answer (score 1):

[The destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx) is called during GC.

Comment: That's funny.  I always heard them referred to as "Finalizers".  Has the nomenclature changed, or was I just mistaken all this time?

Comment: I think this depends on the language. It seems that in C#, *destructor* refers to the language construct that implements *finalization*. In C++/CLI however, the language construct called *destructor* (e.g. `~class() {...}`) actually implements the *IDispose* interface, while there is a new language construct called a *finalizer* (e.g. `!class() {...}`) which is the same as a *destructor* in C#.

Comment: Yeah, but that means I have to create a destructor that calls something like this.ReleaseLogger().  Not a bad idea, but something I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: @Darin: actually the destructor is called _after_ the GC has detected that the object is unreachable, but _before_ the object memory is actually reclaimed (and the memory is reclaimed only if the object remain unreachable, as destructors have the power to reanimate dead objects).